# How to attach the debugger to Android Auto launched with the emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-auto

How to attach the debugger to `Android Auto` launched with the emulator? I need to use breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I am using it, however on occasion debugger just gets disconnected:

1. Run the app normally and open it up on mobile phone, run the head unit emulator as well
2. [Run the "Attach debugger to android process", select your app in the next window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5avzM.png)
3. That should be it, when you put breakpoints into your android auto code the debugger should now stop there.